# Disable Chrome debugging for Cordova Release App

Tags: cordova

I tend to debug my Cordova app using Chrome and Safari's "Inspect on Device" type features, i.e. in Chrome the bottom option in this menu:

[image: "Inspect Devices" in Chrome]

For the release version of the app though I'd like even people with dev mode devices to not be able to inspect the JS source of the app in Cordova's web view. I can't find anything documenting it, does anybody know if it's possible to disable this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you do cordova build --release the inspect will be disabled

Update:
Since Cordova 5.0.0 the build system uses gradle.
See this thread for more info: [Specify signing config for Gradle and Cordova 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106468/specify-signing-config-for-gradle-and-cordova-5)

Comment: I actually figured this out a while ago but forgot about this post. Anyway, it works, obviously. :) Thanks for your reply, @cdarken!

Comment: I thought this could be useful to other people in case you actually found the solution since june, as I myself was searching for it before finding out the correct answer.

Comment: @Scratch., what exactly does not work? I've just upgraded to cordova 5.1.1 and it worked just as before

Comment: still can see my app inside chrome://inspector

Comment: @SantinoWang, I had the same problem. Did you figure this out?