# Specify signing config for Gradle and Cordova 5

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

In correspondence with Cordova [news](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2015/04/21/tools-release.html) version 5.0.0 is ready. I tried to upgrade all my Android projects like it was usually.

To update Cordova framework itself:

```
npm update -g cordova
```

To update library in Android project:

```
cordova platform update android
```

After building new version using "--release" option:

```
cordova build android --release
```

I got only unsigned version. Strange...
So how is it possible to reuse existing keystore (previously generated by keytool and used by Cordova 4.0.0) to get signed APK?

Comment: please check this too - http://stackoverflow.com/a/31585543/1923045

Comment: @KrIsHnA, I am sure 7th May is before than 23rd July ;)

Comment: yeah, I too think the same. :) I thought someone like me will check the comments for a quick answer later. (y|n)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It looks like **Cordova 5.0.0** uses **Gradle** build automation system instead of **Ant**. So original settings for keystore defined in the file "/platforms/android/ant.properties" will not be used during building. So we will get unsigned APK as a result.

To solve this issue we need to tell Gradle to use existing keystore as well. Investigation of build.gradle gives us useful information that we need to provide signingConfigs.

But it is bad idea to do that in this file because it is labelled as auto-generated and it should be free of any editing.

So finally I have found the way to solve it. Object "signingConfigs" will be constructed from file with filename stored in *cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile*.  In correspondence with documentation the default value of this variable is "*release-signing.properties*". So we need just to create new file with such name in the same folder as "*build.gradle*" file and put inside the following content:

```
storeFile=..\\..\\some-keystore.keystore
storeType=jks
keyAlias=some-key
// if you don't want to enter the password at every build, you can store it with this
keyPassword=your-key-password
storePassword=your-store-password
```

Path in example is specified for keystore saved in the project root directory. It has Windows style... In case of Linux you will need to use single slashes (not double backslashes like in above example).

In addition you can set your own path for signing settings file.
To read more about that check the edge version of [cordova documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide/platforms/android/tools.html).

Comment: Nice, but I think this has a problem, because you have to mantein a file in a platform speciffic folder. Maybe there's a way to create a hook that put that file in android folder? I'm trying with not success (My first time with hooks). Any clue?

Comment: Gradle files are required to build Android version. So it looks very straightforward to have all configuration files there. But you can create some file like build-release-android.cmd (build-release-android.sh)  and put all commands there: 1. command for copying of config file 2. "cordova build android --release" command.

Comment: @SebastiánRojasR What you are talking about is not specific for this question / answer. I fix this by creating a crossplatform directory on the same level as the plugin directory and config.xml in the project. I add files for android that need to be copied from there to the android build project result. Check out this article from Holly Schinsky on how to copy files from a non-platform specific location (see the part on copying images and edit that script): 

http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/

Comment: to clarify we need the put the configuration in `platform/android/release-signing.properties`

Answer (score 45):

According to [official documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/platforms/android/tools.html)  (v5.1.1+)  I've just added a **build.json**

```
{
     "android": {
         "release": {
             "keystore": "android.keystore",
             "storePassword": "storepassword",
             "alias": "mykey",
             "password" : "password",
             "keystoreType": ""
         }
     }
 }
```

and my existing **android.keystore** file in the root cordova folder.

**`cordova build android --release`** will do the trick, no hooks needed, the singned apk-file can then be found in *./platform/android/build/outputs/apk* as **android-release.apk**
.

Comment: Which folder did you put this build.json?

Comment: @albertleao to the root of the project, from my trials, it's also simple to just put the .keystore to the root too, as Ronny suggests

Comment: Is there a way to put the build.json and keystore files into another folder?

Comment: This worked, but it seems that the path to the keystore is always considered to be relative to the build file, i.e. you can't put "D:\\SomeFolder\\mystore.keystore", you have to get to it using relative path ("..\..\SomeFolder\mystore.keystore", or similar)

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks for sharing! Do you know if there is a way to automatically change the name of the generated .apk file?

Comment: Make sure you have the latest node.js/npm. This requires an "isAbsolute" call which I got burned on.

Comment: Note to taco users. You can just add the build.json file in the root of your project. Same directory as taco.json and it will sign your android app.

Comment: Working with cordova 6.0.0

Comment: What is the difference between the 'storePassword' and the 'password'?  I created my keystore using `keytool`, entered all the data and the password...and now have myApp.keystore compiled.  I am assuming that password used is the `storePassword`.  If so, then where does `password` come from?

Comment: @veljkoz - I tried your relative path as: `"keystore": "\users\rpo\dev\appkeys\thisApp1.keystore",`  and I got an error: `Error: Unexpected token s` - its not liking the path.  And that path is a direct system root path to the .keystore.

Comment: @rolinger When using the keytool correct, you have to enter the keystore password first, then some data like name and at the end the key password. If you hit there just return, it should be the same.

Comment: Still working on cordova 6.5.0 and android platform version 6.2.2

Answer (score 8):

**For cordova 5.1.1+, refer to Ronny Elflein r11lein answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30980293/2163398**

The current answer is good (by @maxim), but we want to keep platform-specific folder untouched, so we can maintain it out of version control. So I created this Hook to automatically copy the "release-signing.properties" file in android folder.

So, first, place your keystore in your project root. Then create the "release-signing.properties" in a the folder config, in the root of your cordova project. Contents (storeFile path in example is specified for keystore saved in the project root directory. It has Windows style... In case of Linux you will need to use single slashes):

```
storeFile=..\\..\\some-keystore.keystore
storeType=jks
keyAlias=some-key
// if you don't want to enter the password at every build, you can store it with this
keyPassword=your-key-password
storePassword=your-store-password
```

Then, add if not exists the "after_prepare" folder inside the "hooks" folder, and crete in it a file called "copy_assets.js".Contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// Files to be copied, with source and destination

var ncp = require('ncp').ncp,
    transfers = [
      {
        'source': './config/android/release-signing.properties',
        'destination': './platforms/android/release-signing.properties'
      }
    ];

ncp.limit = 16;

transfers.forEach(function(transfer) {
  ncp(transfer.source, transfer.destination, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
    }
    console.log('====== Assets moved from ' + transfer.source + ' to ' + transfer.destination + ' ======');
  });
});
```

If you don't hace ncp in your project, open a command promt in the project folder root and run the command (it's posible you need to create a a packages.json file in your project root):

```
npm install ncp
```

Then, you can run:

```
cordova build android --release
```

Comment: Both this and top answer are rock solid.  Good use of hooks!

Comment: I tried @Ronny Elflein r11lein answer and work perfectly...now cordova generates automatcally the release-signing.properties from build.json file

Comment: why make it simple when you can have it complex?! :) I'd like to use  @Ronny 's approach, but no luck so far... Does this aproach needs a recent version of cordova, gradle?

Comment: Yes! upgraded to 5.1.1 using `sudo npm install -g cordova` and now the @Ronny answer works fine!

Comment: Can anyone point me to some resources re: "hooks"? Is this a UNIX construct/concept?

Answer (score 4):

To automate build release process you should create "build.json" on your project's folder and include the following content:

```
{
 "android": {
     "release": {
         "keystore": "android.keystore",
         "storePassword": "storepassword",
         "alias": "mykey",
         "password" : "password",
         "keystoreType": ""
     }
 }
}
```

The keytore is generated using

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

If you already have a keystore file just run the command below to know the required content

```
keytool -list -keystore .keystore
```

Then you just have to run

```
cordova build android --release
```

Comment: What is the difference between the 'storePassword' and the 'password'?  I created my keystore using `keytool`, entered all the data and the password...and now have myApp.keystore compiled.  I am assuming that password used is the `storePassword`.  If so, then where does `password` come from?

Answer (score 2):

Steps
- 1) Generate keystore certificate

```
Syntax -  keytool -genkey -v -keystore C:\DIR\APPNAME.keystore -alias APPNAME -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

- 2) Copy generated keystore file and paste in cd platforms\android
- 3) Specify signing config for Gradle
   Create file property file - release-signing.properties (file name)
      Write bellow keys and values

  Syntax

  ```
          storeFile=..\\..\\some-keystore.keystore
          storeType=jks (pkcs12 for p12,jks for keystore)
          keyAlias=some-key
          // if you don't want to enter the password at every build, you can store it with this
          keyPassword=your-key-password
          storePassword=your-store-password
  ```

Example

```
        storeFile= abc.keystore
        storePassword=mypass
        storeType=jks
        keyAlias=abc
        keyPassword=mypass
```

- 4) Build cordova project

cordova build android --release

- 5) Run cordova project

cordova run android --release

- 6) Relese APK created in following path -

platforms\android\build\outputs\apk

Answer (score 1):

In the latest gradle version it is also possible to create a file named "release-signing.properties" at the "\platforms\android\" folder. The contents should be:

```
storeFile=<your key>.keystore
storeType=jks
keyAlias=<your_alias>
keyPassword=<your_passwd>
storePassword=<your_passwd>
```

The file ".keystore" should be in the same folder.

Comment: Worth remembering - whilst keytool lets you work with passwords and aliases that are non-alphanumeric Cordova appears to have trouble with these.  In my own case I spent a fair amount of time till I realized that Cordova did not like the exclamation marks in my passwords